# How to expand a string with PHP, using the FROM and TO numbers specified within square brackets?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Let’s say I have the string `http://www.example.com/images/[1-12].jpg`. I would like to expand it into:

> `http://www.example.com/images/1.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/2.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/3.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/4.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/5.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/6.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/7.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/8.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/9.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/10.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/11.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/12.jpg`

Here is my code:

```
$str = "http://www.example.com/images/[1-12].jpg";
while(preg_match_all("/^([^\\[\\]]*)\\[(\\d+)\\-(\\d+)\\](.*)$/m", $str, $mat)){
$arr = array();
$num = sizeof($mat[0]);
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
        for($j = $mat[2][$i]; $j <= $mat[3][$i]; $j++){
        $arr[] = rtrim($mat[1][$i].$j.$mat[4][$i]);
        }
    }
$str = implode(PHP_EOL, $arr);
}
```

It works fine even if I change `$str` to a more complex expression like the following:

```
$str = "http://www.example.com/images/[1-4]/[5-8]/[9-14].jpg";
```

But, unfortunately, zero-padded integers are not supported. So, if I begin with:

```
$str = "http://www.example.com/images/[001-004].jpg";
```

Expected result:

> `http://www.example.com/images/001.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/002.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/003.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/004.jpg`

And the actual result:

> `http://www.example.com/images/001.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/2.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/3.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/4.jpg`

How to change this behaviour so that my code produces the expected result? Also, what are the other shortcomings of my code? Should I really do it with the `while` loop and `preg_match_all` or are there faster alternatives?

**UPDATE:** Changing the seventh line of my code into

```
$arr[] = rtrim($mat[1][$i].str_pad($j, strlen($mat[2][$i]), 0, STR_PAD_LEFT).$mat[4][$i]);
```

seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot to sjagr for suggesting this. My question is still open because I would like to know the shortcomings of my code and faster alternatives (if any).

Comment: How about [`str_pad`](http://www.php.net/str_pad) to force padding based on size of the matched string?

Comment: @sjagr You’re awesome! Please add an answer so that I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Is it a user-submitted string or your own string? If user-submitted, you may need to validate the string because the user may submit something like `http://www.example.com/images/[12-1].jpg`, causing the string to disappear completely! My suggestion: create an array `$range = range($mat[2][$i], $mat[3][$i]);` within the first `for` loop and then use a `foreach` loop instead of the second `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @SoumalyoBardhan's request, my suggestion/answer:

If you use [`str_pad()`](http://www.php.net/str_pad), you can force the padding based on the size of the matched string using `strlen()` found by your match. Your usage of it looks good to me:

```
$arr[] = rtrim($mat[1][$i].str_pad($j, strlen($mat[2][$i]), 0, STR_PAD_LEFT).$mat[4][$i]);
```

I really can't see what else could be improved with your code, although I don't exactly understand how `preg_match_all` would be used in a `while` statement.

Comment: The function [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/preg-match-all) “Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.”

Comment: @SharanyaDutta Ah so it will keep finding matches until an error is reached

Comment: Or, until there are no more matches.

Answer (score 1):

A faster alternative with `preg_split` which also supports descending order (FROM > TO):

```
$str = "http://www.example.com/images/[12-01].jpg";
$spl = preg_split("/\\[([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\\]/", $str, -1, 2);
$size = sizeof($spl);
$arr = array("");
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
$temp = array();
    if($i%3 == 1){
    $range = range($spl[$i], $spl[$i+1]);
    $len = min(strlen($spl[$i]), strlen($spl[++$i]));
        foreach($arr as $val){
            foreach($range as $ran){
            $temp[] = $val.str_pad($ran, $len, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        foreach($arr as $val){
        $temp[] = $val.$spl[$i];
        }
    }
$arr = $temp;
}
$str = implode(PHP_EOL, $arr);
print($str);
```

It has the following result:

> `http://www.example.com/images/12.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/11.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/10.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/09.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/08.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/07.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/06.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/05.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/04.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/03.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/02.jpg`
>   `http://www.example.com/images/01.jpg`

Comment: Faster indeed. I tested with `$str = "http://www.example.com/images/[001-300]/[1-10]/[1-10].jpg";` and your code (0.21 seconds) defeated mine (0.39 seconds) by a difference of 0.18 seconds. Moreover, the support for descending order is brilliant. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are two things in your code which I don’t understand. First, what’s the purpose of `++$i` inside the `if($i%3 == 1){ ... }` block? Isn’t it the same as having a `if($i%3 == 2){ continue; }` block? Why do we need to skip particular values of `$i`? Second, how have you achieved the zero-padding without `STR_PAD_LEFT`? As far as I know, the function `str_pad` defaults to `STR_PAD_RIGHT` which is certainly not the expected behaviour of your code.

Comment: You may see what’s inside the array `$spl` (using `print_r` or `var_dump`) in order to understand that we must take two values of the array together (i.e. `$spl[$i]` and `$spl[$i+1]`) while creating the array `$range`. Since we have no more business with `$spl[$i+1]`, we may proceed to `$spl[$i+2]`. And yes, I could have used an `else if($i%3 == 2){ continue; }` block but avoided it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: The function `str_pad` defaults to `STR_PAD_RIGHT` when the fourth argument is omitted. But I’ve used `0` as the fourth argument which is nothing but the value of the constant `STR_PAD_LEFT`. Sometimes I find writing the name of the constant cumbersome and go for the value instead. Sorry if it lessens the intelligibility of the code.

Comment: Great code, great explanation! You have absolutely no reason to be sorry, Sharanya. Thanks, thanks, thanks a lot.